# If-statement condtion reduction

Tags: perl, if-statement, conditional-statements

Suppose it is:

```
...
use Config::Properties::Simple;
...
my $p = Config::Properties::Simple->new( file => $propfile );
...
$str = $p->getProperty('prop');
...
```

.

Does

```
 ...
if ( defined $str and $str ne "" ) { #1
 ...
```

equal to

```
...
if ($str) { #2
...
```

?

If not, is there a way to simplify the `#1` marked statement?

Comment: `if (($str // '') ne '') { ... }`

Comment: Yes, those are equal. And, how could you simplify #2?

Comment: It is logical false if undefined, "", and 0. There is the interesting special case of 0E0, zero in exponential notation, which is a logical true.

Comment: @ddoxey , The string `0E0` is true, but then so is the string `0.0`, `-0` and every single string except for the empty string and `0`. There's nothing special about `0E0`.

Comment: @ikegami, Point taken. There are many strings equal to zero which are logically true:
perl -Tw -e 'print 0E0 == 0 ? "true\n" : "false\n";'
perl -Tw -e 'print 0E0 ? "true\n" : "false\n";'

Comment: @ddoxey, There are infinitly many strings equal to zero which are logically zero: All of them except the empty string and the string `0`. /// Your second snippet false cause you used the number zero instead of the string `0E0`.

Comment: @ddoxey Why are you using taint checks `-T` in your one-liner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not the same if `$str` is `"0"`.

You can simplify the statement by just checking the length:

```
if (length $str) { ...
```

In recent versions of Perl, `length(undef)` is `undef` without any warning generated.  And using `undef` as a boolean doesn't generate a warning either.

(By "recent" I mean [5.12 and up](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#Other-potentially-incompatible-changes).  Previously, `length(undef)` would produce "Use of uninitialized value in length" if you have warnings turned on, which you should.)

Answer (score 3):

1. No. It's different for `$str=0;` and `$str="0";` for starters.
2. Maybe. Depends on what values `$str` can have, what you are checking for and what version of Perl you want to support. Possibilities:

   - `if ($str)`
   - `if (length($str))`
   - `if (defined($str))`